# How to handle the scenario in which after entering text in textbox and clicking on find button trigger a javascript using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am testing a web application in which i am facing an issue that when clicking on find button after entering some text in texbox the page refresh and same deafult page shows up in place of search result because it(find button) is calling a javascript function on click.

Although i have found a  temporary solution by putting the Thread.sleep() after input and then clicking on button but it is not reflecting search criteria then i have to refresh the page to get the proper search results.

I want to learn a better way to handle this kind of case.

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use Selenium's Wait class to wait for element to be present.

**Ruby:**

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new {
    driver.find_element(:name, "q")
}
```

**Java:**
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
...
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("search_btn"))
);
```